# How to "join" 2 indices and search in ElasticSearch?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, join

Suppose I have an index called "posts" with the following properties:

```
{
    "uid": "<user id>",
    "date": "<some date>",
    "message": "<some message>"
}
```

And another index called "users" with the following properties:

```
{
    "uid": "<user id>",
    "gender": "Male"
}
```

Now, I'm searching for posts posted by people who are males. How can I do that?

I definitely don't want to have a "user" property in a post and store the gender of the user in there. Because when a user updates his/her gender, I'd have to go to every single post that he/she has ever posted to update the gender.

Comment: You would want to use parent-child mapping https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html

Comment: denormalizing is the key here. Updating all records can be easily done using the Update-by-Query API in a single call, nothing complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch doesn't support inter index relation till now. There is 'join' datatype but it supports only fields within the same index.